# Developer unlock Windows Phone 8 : Error Code 0x64

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

We need to unlock a Windows Phone 8 device in order to deploy our app that still supports this specific platform.
The process was working some months ago without any problem but now, **Windows Phone Developer Registration Tool**, available with SDK 8.0, returns the following error:

[image]

We have already tried with different devices (with the date set correctly: UTC +1 Rome)

- HTC 8S
- Lumia 720
- Nokia 625

all with the same result.
We have tried to unlock our devices for an entire week, so it does not seem a temporary problem.

The devices and the pc have both a working Internet Connection and aren't running behind any firewall/proxy at all.

We have no problem at all, unlocking WP 8.1 devices with the proper **Windows Phone Developer Registration Tool for WP 8.1**

Do you know if there's any technical problem on the Microsoft side?
Is the Windows Phone WP 8.0 unlocking process still supported by Microsoft?

Comment: I removed both the [tag:microsoft] tag (because the tag itself says "do not use", and further to this Meta discussion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293754/82548) and the [tag:unlock] tag, since that tag seems to be about unlocking the device from its dormant/standby state.

Comment: have you gone through following link :http://www.kodyaz.com/windows-phone-8/windows-phone-developer-registration-for-app-development.aspx

Comment: @NullPointer yes, I have already checked it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of May 13, 2015, you can no longer developer unlock Windows Phone 8.0 devices.  You have to upgrade them to Windows Phone 8.1.  I don't have an article to point to, just an email I received from MS to the email address associated with my developer account:

> If you have a Windows Phone 8.0 device that you use to test your apps,
>   please read this mail.
>
> The Windows Phone 8.0 certificate that validates developer unlocks
>   will expire today May 13, 7pm, Pacific Daylight time.
>
> We recommend that you re-unlock your Windows Phone 8.0 test devices
>   prior to today 7pm, to continue testing for another 24 months.
>
> After today, no Windows Phone 8.0 device will be able to be developer
>   unlocked, and you will have three options to continue testing Windows
>   Phone 8.0 packages:  –    Update the phone to Windows Phone 8.1 and
>   unlock it for developer testing – Submit apps as beta through the
>   Windows Dev Center and test with Windows Phone 8.0 devices –  Test
>   Windows Phone 8.0 apps via the Windows Phone emulator
>
> Any Windows Phone 8.0 device currently unlocked will continue to be
>   unlocked and work as a test device until its certificate expires. To
>   maximize the time available to test with this device, please lock then
>   unlock the device before May 13, 2015 7pm PDT.
>
> Note that this change has no impact on apps available in the Windows
>   Phone Store, has no impact on Windows Phone 8.1 devices, nor will it
>   impact customers with Windows Phone 8.x devices.
>
> The Windows Store team

Comment: And what if you can not upgrade your device to 8.1. Or registration is the only way to do so?

Comment: You could ask MS if there is a workaround, but it's my understanding from the email above that you can no longer unlock WP8.0 devices, period.  If your device can not be upgraded to 8.1, you can't use it as a test device.

Comment: I just get a response from Microsoft that is pretty clear:

> I am responding to the service request you created and I did understand that you are trying to unlock a windows phone 8.0 device, but you are having issues. You can no longer unlock a window phone 8.0 device. You would need to upgrade to windows phone 8.1. Please read the link below.
 
> [App developers won't be able to unlock Windows Phone 8.0 devices](http://www.windowscentral.com/app-developers-wont-be-able-unlock-windows-phone-80-devices-after-today)
 
> Please let me know if you have any questions. Look forward to your response

Comment: It would be nice if the error message told you that you can't unlock WP8.0 devices.  Instead of the ridiculously misleading "Error communicating with windows phone dev center" error.

Answer (score 5):

I tried registering my Lumia 820 using WP8 SDK Registration tool and it succeeded. So I believe there is no technical problem on Microsoft's server.

It is still possible to unlock Windows phone 8.0 devices. Only 7.x devices can't be unlocked now as mentioned in [this article](http://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-ends-unlocking-windows-phone-7x-devices-developers-dec-31)

As you are getting time error, Try disabling "Set Time automatically" from Settings menu as per the official documentation

> Are the date and time set correctly on the phone? In SETTINGS | date + time, turn off the Set automatically setting and then retry registration. After registration succeeds, turn this setting on again.

Comment: I have tried it in IST(+5:30)
And I believe this could be source of an error too. Make sure that the country(Time Zone) in your Microsoft account matches the one on your PC and phone.

Comment: But it does not explain why the same account works on WP 8.1.

Comment: Microsoft has a different registration tool for Windows phone 8.1. Maybe they fixed it with WP 8.1 so that it doesn't cause an issue.

Comment: I've installed SDK 8.0 and now Visual Studio 2013 which includes both SDK 8.0 and 8.1. And as I can see the tools to register WP8.0 devices and WP8.1 devices are different. Or seems to be different registration mechanism by Microsoft for both OS.

Comment: While searching I found one useful [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/7d24f5be-fe62-4d7e-86cf-e98925ce9f1d/phone-registration-tool-troubleshooting) which points out many factors which could cause this issue. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Yes, I've already checked that link found on the Microsoft forum. Anyway I've tried all  the possible  combinations with Time Zone and Date settings, but  no way, the problem  persists. I'm starting to  believe that could be a problem  related to the firmware of our  devices.

Comment: This morning I've tried for the last time and magically it started to work again. I don't know, maybe somebody at Microsoft side has read this post :). Thanks for your support and enjoy the deserved Bounty.

Comment: Thank you so much :)
And anyways as you might have received the email as well. Microsoft is going to stop support for unlocking Windows Phone 8 devices now.

`The Windows Phone 8.0 certificate that validates developer unlocks will expire today May 13, 7pm, Pacific Daylight time.` and also `After today, no Windows Phone 8.0 device will be able to be developer unlocked`

Comment: that's hilarious. Probably the problems I had, was related to this imminent end of support.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your *phone* also has some internet connection, such as wifi.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some problems sometimes registering some WP devices as developer devices. I've never had this particular error, but maybe this will work.

When the device is connected to the computer, in the taskbar click in the icon which shows that a device is connected (the one where you can "Safely remove" the device) and right click on it and select the show devices and printers option. When it opens, you will see all the windows phone devices you have connected to the computer. Disconnect your device and uninstall it and its drivers by selecting the appropriate option after right clicking on it.

Connect it again, it should now install its drivers again.

And just in case, if you have the correct date/time on the device, just confirm they also match the region/location set in the device. for eg- suppose you have set the time to indian standard time (IST) but the region of the device is set to that of USA or some other location.

Comment: "And just in case, if you have the correct date/time on the device, just confirm they also match the region/location set in the device".. What does that mean?

Comment: @systempuntoout In WP8 settings, there are two different options - one is date+time - used to set the date/time, the other is language+region - used to set the region/location/language of the device

Answer (score 1):

If the WP8.0 answer or other date/time finagling does not help, another recommendation to try is to just reboot the darn thing after changing the time settings to manual.

I ran into this error with a Windows 10 Phone today.  I tried adjusting the time settings from automatically set to manual, and ensured all was in sync between the Phone and PC, but I still received the 0x64 error code.  I tried another PC, to no avail.  By chance, I decided to reboot the phone.  After rebooting and launching the PhoneReg tool, all was happy and I was able to unlock the phone and deploy my app.

Answer (score 1):

Check windows phone date+time = pc date+time

date+time Set automatically turned off

unplug de phone and reconnect

Comment: Please elaborate why this would work.  Otherwise this answer may get deleted.